# MySQL on VMware for High Availability

Tags: vmware-vsphere, high-availability, mysql-replication, mysql-cluster

Given a choice between the current database-level HA options for MySQL, like Master-Master, Cluster, or Galera, and vSphere HA for the machine running the MySQL master, which would you use or combine and why?

Comment: Given that VMware HA will, at best, reboot the MySQL Master on another box, and then have to wait for InnoDB recovery, what other replication and HA techniques should be used on top of VMware? I'm looking for a set of solutions that "play nicely together"

Answer (score 1):

vSphere HA will not give you 100% uptime.  If a host fails, all of the VMs that were running on that host will be restarted on another host, provided that there are enough resources (CPU & memory).  If you want a higher uptime using vSphere, then you will want to look into Fault Tolerance.  It essentially runs the VM on 2 hosts concurrently and therefore uses twice the CPU and memory as HA.  However, if you are using Mysql master-master, cluster, etc. then you are probably using the same amount of resources as FT.

If you want to use Mysql master-master or cluster in a vSphere environment, then you can configure VMWare DRS rules to keep the guest VMs on separate hosts.  This would be beneficial in case one of the hosts fails.

Comment: another issue is that ft limits the amount and type of hardware that you can present to the guest.